# Significato e uso di un "quarto di" in questo contesto

Tags: word-usage, meaning

Nella prefazione a *Nostro lunedí* di Silvio D'Arzo ho letto:

> «Che umanità... che umanità» dicevamo, ed eravamo magari capaci di organizzare in settimana un convegno con l’intervento di qualche **quarto di gloria** locale, e poi ecco: tutto quello che usciva da noi era questo e nient’altro che questo: una colonna o anche mezza o anche meno, piú lucida e fredda del nikel.

Non sono sicura di capire del tutto bene il senso dell'espressione "quarto di gloria".
Significa una persona che ha un certo prestigio (secondo quanto è scritto, a livello locale), ma che veramente non è degna di tale prestigio? Si può usare la locuzione "un quarto di" in altre espressioni con un senso simile? Oppure si tratta di un'invenzione di D'Arzo?

Comment: La tua ipotesi è sostanzialmente corretta, ma secondo me più che non è degna di tale prestigio, l'espressione evidenzia quanto questo prestigio sia una "fetta" assai limitata (al 25% appunto).
Non escludo però che l'espressione possa contenere un richiamo all'espressione "quarto di nobiltà" (forse sarcastico?).

Comment: Per quel che conta, anche a me ha fatto pensare ai “quarti di nobiltà”.